# Google drive API Get file id having the name

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Is it possible to get the id of a file in google drive having the name, extension and path of this file? I've been looking for this but I'm not finding

I think it's listing all the files using some sort of filter by name, right? But how do I get the id after this?

Comment: I am trying to list the files, appeared some doubts I am solving in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179724/list-file-google-drive
After listing all I will try to find out the method to get the ID and anything I ask here. (Just to keep from topic topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually try the method [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get). From this, you will be able to get a file metadata in which the "fileId" was included.

There is also a supplied [PHP code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples) specific for this method. You can [try it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it).